# SQL Query with Join, Count and Where

Tags: sql, join, count, where-clause

I have 2 tables and am trying to do one query to save myself some work.

```
Table 1: id, category id, colour
Table 2: category id, category name
```

I want to join them so that I get `id, category id, category name, colour`

Then I want to limit it so that no "red" items are selected (`WHERE colour != "red"`)
Then I want to count the number of records in each category (`COUNT(id) GROUP BY (category id`).

I have been trying:

```
SELECT COUNT(table1.id), table1.category_id, table2.category_name 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.category_id=table2.category_id 
WHERE table1.colour != "red"
```

But it just doesn't work. I've tried lots of variations and just get no results when I try the above query.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to use `GROUP BY` so you will have multiple records returned,

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) TotalCount, 
        b.category_id, 
        b.category_name 
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.category_id = b.category_id 
WHERE   a.colour <> 'red'
GROUP   BY b.category_id, b.category_name
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), table1.category_id, table2.category_name 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.category_id=table2.category_id 
WHERE table1.colour <> 'red'
GROUP BY table1.category_id, table2.category_name
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used sub-query and it worked great!

```
SELECT *,(SELECT count(*) FROM $this->tbl_news WHERE
$this->tbl_news.cat_id=$this->tbl_categories.cat_id) as total_news FROM
$this->tbl_categories
```